# Fullcalendar, recurring allDay events don't align/stack up correctly/show up in the right order

Tags: stack, fullcalendar, alignment

My problem is that when I add more then one recurring allDay event and am viewing say 1.May to 7.May, they don't stack right, the order is wrong, for example on 1.May I have event with id 1 then event with id 3 and then event with id 2 but on 2.May I have 1 2 3, so the events don't align.

I thought that when they got added, if I ordered them by ID they'd stack up correctly, since only id 1 would be added first and then under that id 2 and so on, I did that by doing data.sort(function(a,b){return a.id - b.id}), but that messed up the order even more for some reason.

How can I align events that have the same id (recurring events)?

Visual example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jppzl.png

I'm using Fullcalendar 1.4.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the bug: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=379

Comment: how can i position the event always on the top of the day if it is coming from previous date?